# Pegar dados de um arquivo.txt e armazenar em uma lista

Tags: python, funções, txt

Como seria uma função para pegar esse .txt e importar nas listas?

Essa função pega os dados das listas e armazena os dados no txt.

```
def guardaTxt(lstModelo, lstCor, lstNumeracao, lstQtd, lstValorUnit):
    file1 = open("sapataria_dados.txt","w")
 
    for x in range(len(lstModelo)):
        file1.write(str(lstModelo[x])+' '+str(lstNumeracao[x])+' '+ \  
                    str(lstQtd[x])+' '+str(lstValorUnit[x])+' '+str(lstCor[x])+'\n')
        
    file1.close()
```

A lista fica armazenada assim:

> Tradicional 42 20 500 Branco
>
> Esportivo 40 10 200 Azul
>
> Caminhada 45 25 600 Amarelo
>
> Corrida 39 15 400 Vermelho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eduardo, abaixo um exemplo de como poderia ser implementada a função para a leitura do TXT (**leTxt**), tentei manter o mesmo padrão da função que você colocou como exemplo para a gravação dos dados no txt.

Seu código está com muitas listas, talvez criar uma classe *Sapato* deixe as coisas mais organizadas.

```
import os

def guardaTxt(lstModelo, lstCor, lstNumeracao, lstQtd, lstValorUnit):
    file1 = open("sapataria_dados.txt","w")

    for x in range(len(lstModelo)):
        file1.write(str(lstModelo[x]) + ' ' + str(lstNumeracao[x]) + ' ' + str(lstQtd[x]) + ' ' + str(lstValorUnit[x]) + ' ' + str(lstCor[x])+'\n')

    file1.close()

#Função responsável pela leitura dos dados de sapato no arquivo txt, mantendo o mesmo formato da função guardaTxt
def leTxt(lstModelo, lstCor, lstNumeracao, lstQtd, lstValorUnit):
  #Verifica a existência do arquivo antes de abrir
  if os.path.isfile("sapataria_dados.txt"):
    file1 = open("sapataria_dados.txt", "r")

    #Efetua a leitura das linhas do arquivo
    for line in file1.readlines():
      #Quebra a linha lida em uma lista, a cada espaço encontrado é gerado um item na lista
      sapato = line.strip().split(' ')

      lstModelo.append(sapato[0])
      lstNumeracao.append(int(sapato[1]))
      lstQtd.append(int(sapato[2]))
      lstValorUnit.append(float(sapato[3]))
      lstCor.append(sapato[4])

    file1.close()


#Valores que serão gravados no txt
modelos = ["Tradicional", "Esportivo", "Caminhada", "Corrida"]
cores = ["Branco", "Azul", "Amarelo", "Vermelho"]
numeracoes = [42, 40, 45, 39]
quantidades = [20, 10, 25, 15]
valores = [500, 200, 600, 400]

#Chamada da função que grava os valores no txt
guardaTxt(modelos, cores, numeracoes, quantidades, valores)

txtModelos = []
txtCores = []
txtNumeracoes = []
txtValores = []
txtQuantidades = []

#Efetua a leitura do txt no mesmo formato que é feita a gravação
leTxt(txtModelos, txtCores, txtNumeracoes, txtQuantidades, txtValores )

#Exibe os valores que foram lidos do txt
print(txtModelos, txtCores, txtNumeracoes, txtValores, txtQuantidades)
```

Comment: Obrigado amigo, meu código esta sem classes porque esse código é para as aulas iniciais de Python.